# How to Implement ASP.Net MVC Interactive Filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Here's my desired result:

Given a ASP.net MVC page that has a block at the top with several parameters for filtering against a list that is display below, something like...

```
TextBox1   RadioButton1   
TextBox2   OtherOptions Here



item
item
item
```

I'd like the filtering to be interactive capable on later iterations or immediately if it's relatively easy.

Any suggestions on an approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This jQuery plugin](http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) may help you. Open "jqGrid Examples" -> "Advanced" -> "Search Big Sets" for sample of filtering and searching. There are a lot of other samples too.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the approach StackOverflow used under the Users and Tags sections of the site.  When you type in the textbox to search, it filters the list as you type.  It would be pretty trivial to add to the filter other options like a radio button, etc...

You can do this relatively easily with jquery by taking advantage of event listeners and the ajax capabilities it has.